# CodeIgniter escaping table

Tags: codeigniter, escaping, codeigniter-3

I know CodeIgniter automatically escapes values being sent to say an insert or update query e.g. `$bar`, but will it also escape `$table` if table is being received from say a post or get? I couldn't find any documentation on that.

```
$this->db->insert($table, array('foo' => $bar));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you look at CodeIgniter's 2.x system/database/drivers/DB_driver.php near line 902

or

at CodeIgniters 3.x system/database/DB_driver near line 1365

you'll find a function called insert_string() which looks like this:

```
/**
     * Generate an insert string
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  the table upon which the query will be performed
     * @param   array   an associative array data of key/values
     * @return  string
     */
    function insert_string($table, $data)
    {
        $fields = array();
        $values = array();

        foreach ($data as $key => $val)
        {
            $fields[] = $this->_escape_identifiers($key);
            $values[] = $this->escape($val);
        }

        return $this->_insert($this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), $fields, $values);
    }
```

then follow-up function _protect_identifiers() near line 1246 (CI 2.x) or near line 1729 (CI 3.0) which says:

```
 * Since the column name can include up to four segments (host, DB, table, column)
 * or also have an alias prefix, we need to do a bit of work to figure this out and
 * insert the table prefix (if it exists) in the proper position, and escape only
 * the correct identifiers.
```

so the answer is YES.

in case of doubt you can always use this: `echo ($this->db->last_query());die();` which prints out your last query performed what could look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `googlemaps_marker` (`descr`, `Lat`, `Lng`, `pretty_url`, `ID`, `zone_ID`, `kind`, `author_id`, `author`, `date_updated`) VALUES ('sasasasdas', '41.27780646738183', '-7.437744140625', 'sasasasdas', 4, 4, 1, '1', 'Admini Istrator', '2017-07-15 18:20:40')
```